# How to extract the noun and its corresponding adjective from the output of stanford parser

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am getting the following output using the **Stanford Core-NLP parser**. Now how can i extract a noun and its corresponding adjective or any required info **related to that particular noun** from the output. I want that all the nouns should be extracted along with their adjectives in order, so that i know which adjective is related to which noun in the text

For example:

I need to extract the noun "Santosh" and its corresponding adjective "handsome" from the below output

```
nn(Santosh-2, Kosgi-1)
nsubj(handsome-4, Santosh-2)
cop(handsome-4, is-3)
root(ROOT-0, handsome-4)
aux(sent-6, has-5)
rcmod(handsome-4, sent-6)
det(email-8, an-7)
dobj(sent-6, email-8)
nn(University-11, Stanford-10)
prep_to(sent-6, University-11
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just started fooling around with stanford parser, so take this with a grain of salt.

What I would do to **extract a noun and its corresponding adjective or any required info related to that particular noun** is:

generate the parse tree for the sentence.   (look at ParserDemo.java for how to do this).

https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/CSC-581-S11-06/browser/trunk/Stanford/stanford-parser-2011-04-20/src/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/demo/ParserDemo.java?rev=2

The parse tree will look like this:

```
  (ROOT
    (S
     (NP (JJ handsome) (NNP Joe) (NNP Blow))
     (VP (VBD sent)
      (NP (DT an) (NN email))
      (PP (TO to)
        (NP (PRP$ his) (JJ congressional) (NN representative))))))
```

for a sentence such as this: 
handsome Joe Blow sent an email to his congressional representative

Then you write some code to recursively descend through the parse tree and pick out the 'NP'  fragments.

For example, one such fragment is (NP (JJ handsome) (NNP Joe) (NNP Blow))

once you have that fragment you can gather up all of the adjectives and any other modifiers you are interested in.   It is helpful to know the meaning of the codes
[ http://bulba.sdsu.edu/jeanette/thesis/PennTags.html ]

I wrote some code to crawl through a parse tree back and extract stuff... this might help you get started >

can't give you all the code,but here's some of it....

```
static {
    nounNodeNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    nounNodeNames.add( "NP");
    nounNodeNames.add( "NPS");
    nounNodeNames.add( "FW");
    nounNodeNames.add( "NN");
    nounNodeNames.add( "NNS");
    nounNodeNames.add( "NNP");
    nounNodeNames.add( "NNPS");
}


public  List<NounPhrase> extractPhrasesFromString(Tree tree, String originalString) {
    List<NounPhrase> foundPhraseNodes = new ArrayList<NounPhrase>();

    collect(tree, foundPhraseNodes);
    logger.debug("parsing " + originalString + " yields " + foundPhraseNodes.size() + " noun node(s).");
    if (foundPhraseNodes.size() == 0) {
        foundPhraseNodes.add(new NounPhrase(tree, originalString));
    }
    return  foundPhraseNodes;
}

private void collect(Tree tree, List<NounPhrase> foundPhraseNodes) {
    if (tree == null || tree.isLeaf()) {
        return;
    }


    Label label = tree.label();
    if (label instanceof CoreLabel) {
        CoreLabel coreLabel = ((CoreLabel) label);

        String text = ((CoreLabel) label).getString(CoreAnnotations.OriginalTextAnnotation.class);
        logger.debug(" got text: " + text);
        if (text.equals("THE")) {
            logger.debug(" got THE text: " + text);
        }

        String category = coreLabel.getString(CoreAnnotations.CategoryAnnotation.class);
        if (nounNodeNames.contains(category)) {
            NounPhrase phrase = null;
            String phraseString = flatten(tree);
            if ((phrase = stringToNounPhrase.get(phraseString)) == null) {
                phrase = new NounPhrase(tree, phraseString);
                stringToNounPhrase.put(phraseString, phrase);
            }

            if (! foundPhraseNodes.contains(phrase)) {
                logger.debug("adding found noun phrase to list: {}", phrase.debug());
                foundPhraseNodes.add(phrase);
            } else {
                logger.debug("on list already, so skipping found noun phrase: {}", phrase.debug());
            }
        }
    }


    List<Tree> kids = tree.getChildrenAsList();
    for (Tree kid : kids) {
        collect(kid, foundPhraseNodes);
    }
}
```